# html5 - nav header article section should I put styling in them?

Tags: html, css

Should I put styling in `nav, header, article, section`?

for intance, HTML5:

```
<body>
  <header>  
    <h1>My super duper page</h1>
    <!-- Header content -->
  </header>
  <div role="main">
    <!-- Page content -->
  </div>
  <aside role="complementary">
    <!-- Secondary content -->
  </aside>
  <footer>
    <!-- Footer content -->
  </footer>
</body>
```

CSS,

```
header {
   margin: 20px;
   padding: 20px;
   color: black;
   font-family: arial;
   font-size: 14px;
   etc...
}
```

Can I do so?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the declaration and major properties. Put in styling if you want, if you don't the content will be shown as default to be left-aligned.
The 3 most popular ways to use CSS are inline, internal, and external. Try to avoid inline.
Side note: HTML5 now has header, nav, main, and footer blocks available now.
A good example (CSS goes in style):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML lang = "en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My Site Title</title>
<style>
header{text-align:center;}
nav{font-weight:bold;}
footer{font-size:.70em;
font-style: italic;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1>My Header</h1>
</header>
<nav>
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
</nav>
<main>
<p>Sample paragraph...</p>
</main>
<footer>
Copyright &copy; 2016
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```